# Android In app Billing Item ID

Tags: android

Long things short: If im testing my In-App-Billing apk in the market i always receive `"RequestPurchase: RESULT_ITEM_UNAVAILABLE"`

Im feeling like a complete idiot atm and ran out of ideas how to fix it.

i call `mBillingService.requestPurchase("itemxx", "")`, wich works fine with static test.purchased.

But as soon as i upload the signed apk as a draft to the android market it doesnt manage to find my predefined item. Mybe the proper Question at this point is: "How does the ID of the Item in the Market has to be "named" relating to the id you made up in your application.

Can anyone provide me with a hint on what else i can try or look up?

```
APP: itemxx -> Market: itemxx
APP: itemxx -> Market: package.name.itemxx
APP: package.name.itemxx -> Market: package.name.itemxx
APP: package.name.itemxx -> Market: itemxx
```

Comment: Did you resolve this, a friend of mine has the same issue. His app is signed, the in-app purchase is published, and has tried googlemail and gmail accounts.

Comment: I am having same issue. If you have any success with it please share your code. I have integrated PayPal it is far more easy to integrate Google In app billing sucks badly for devs.

Comment: Sorry. I still havent found a solution, stuck in other work ^^ But i'll keep on track and post a solution if i figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the Problem for me. I use the Sample Code from this resource:
http://www.anddev.org/advanced-tutorials-f21/simple-inapp-billing-payment-t52060.html, thanks for that Mr. @Blundell.

Besides changing the Package-Name to get it up and running it turned out that the ID in the app and in the Market has just to be the same, simple as that.

So i call `BillingHelper.requestPurchase(mContext, "item.hacke");`
and create an Item for the Application in Android market with the ID `item.hacke`.

Take care of the following Steps:

1. Enter the Correct Public Key
2. Use a different gmail account for your tests than the publisher account and enter the mail address as Test-Account right below the PublicKey
3. Make sure the item in the market is published. Only the Item not the App.

good luck :D

Comment: Maybe i should note that it works with account-emails @googlemail.com, there were some statements on other Questions stating that market is only accessible for @gmail.com accounts.